# Prove the inequality....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $x,y$ be positive reals such that $x+y=2$. Prove that :
>
> $x^3y^3(x^3+y^3) \leq 2$
>
> Source : INMO 2002

My attempt :

I started with the left side of the inequality to be proved.

$x^3y^3(x^3+y^3) = x^3y^3(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy) = 2 x^3y^3(x^2+y^2+2xy-3xy)$

$=2x^3y^3(4-3xy)$

How to proceed ?

Do I have to some AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz on particular set of values ?

Comment: Just a note, there is very useful tool to find whether someone asked same question here, you can find it here: https://approach0.xyz/ (just insert the inequality there and it will search, it performs some nifty substitutions etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly done.

Applying AM-GM gives us that $$  xy \times xy  \times xy \times (4-3xy) \le  \frac {(4-3xy+xy+xy+xy)^4}{4^4}=1$$

Comment: O Wow !!! That solved problem.. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

Proceeding afterwards, we need to prove that $$x^3y^3 (4-3xy)\leq 1$$ Now we apply AM-GM inequality to the positive reals $4-3xy, xy, xy, xy $ and we obtain  $$(xy)^3 (4-3xy) \leq (\frac {4-3xy+3xy}{4})^4 \leq 1$$ Hope it helps.